# Apache RewriteRule modify request_uri

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Based on a condition I want Apache to change the REQUEST_URI and then proxy the new REQUEST_URI to a different webserver

This should be fairly wasy to do, however, all the examples on the internet do not give me any result.

So for example my URL: http://my.domain.com/otherserver/dir2/page1.html?param1=true%param2=10
Based on the beginning of REQUEST_URI I want to modify the REQUEST_URI to /dir2/page1.html?param1=true%param2=10 and pass this on the other webserver

For instance

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/otherserver
RewriteRule ^(.*) ^/otherserver / [N]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8080%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
```

However, this does not give the desired result.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try doing this differently, e.g. use `mod_proxy` instead of the `P` flag to `mod_rewrite` (see [the `mod_rewrite` documentation for the `P` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_p) where it says, "Avoid this flag and prefer [`mod_proxy` directives] wherever possible", and also [When Not To Use Rewrite](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite)).

If I understand properly, the behavior you want is "for all requests of the form `^/otherserver(.*)`, proxy the request to `http://localhost:8080$1`." The [When Not To Use Rewrite page](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite) suggests this can be done as

```
ProxyPass /otherserver http://localhost:8080/
```

...but confirm that in [the `mod_proxy` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) before taking my word for it.